# How to export class with coffeescript in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

file1:

```
module.exports = {
    class Verify
      myMethod: ->
        # return stuff
```

and file2:

```
Verify    = require('excelTest.js')
verify    = new Verify
verify    = verify.myMethod()
```

Above Failing with:

```
Running "coffee:glob_to_multiple" (coffee) task
>> server/api/abrechnung/excelTest.coffee:7:2: error: unexpected class
>>  class Verify
>>  ^^^^^
>> In file: server/api/abrechnung/excelTest.coffee
>> On line: 6
>>  class Verify
>>  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports.Verify = class Verify
  mymethod: -> 
  ..
```

Or, probably more readable, separate the class definition and its export:

```
class Verify
  mymethod: ->
  ..

module.exports =
  Verify: Verify
```

In both cases it would then be `require('excelTest.js').Verify`; leave out the extra `Verify` if you just want `require('excelTest.js')`.